# How to insert datetime into `created` column only when a record is created first time

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

- I need a solution to insert datetime into `created` column **only when a
  record is created first time**.

I've found this example but it works for `onUpdate` style so it updates `updated` column every time when a record is updated.

```
/**
 * @var datetime $updated
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $updated;

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function setUpdatedPrePersist()
{
    $this->updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy and reliable solution is to require the following extension in your composer:
https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst

And then update your entity simply adding this:

```
<?php
// src/YourCompany/YourBundle/Entity/Demo.php

namespace YourCompany\YourBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Demo
{
    // ....
    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updated
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated;

}
```

That's it! :)

Note: Make sure you enable the timestampable listener in your configuration, ie:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true
```

If you don't like standing on the shoulders of giants:

```
<?php
// src/YourCompany/YourBundle/Entity/Demo.php

namespace YourCompany\YourBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Demo
{

    // ...

    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updated
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $updated;


    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function onPrePersist()
    {
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
        $this->updated = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function onPreUpdate()
    {
        $this->updated = new \DateTime();
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: This is (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504997/symfony2-datetime-best-way-to-store-timestamps) what I've found before which is similar to your but I thought there could be an example like mine.

Comment: I've added how to do what you asked for without using that bundle. Even though I don't understand why, that library is widely used and tested. ;)

As a side note, what you'll be doing there is basically the same as what you do using the Doctrine extensions, both listen to the Doctrine events and update the right datetime field. The difference is that this way you have to write the methods yourself, if you use the extensions you can just put the annotations in all the entities you need to be timestampable and the built in listeners will take care of everything.