# Symfony2 - Doctrine fixtures createdAt showing up as an hour ahead of actual time

Tags: symfony, time, doctrine-orm, fixtures

This hasn't happened to me before, but I just noticed that all my dummy fixture information (posts) are showing up with a createdAt time an hour ahead of actual time?

When I manually enter in a post the time is correct.

Any idea what is causing this?

I am using a Timestampable entity file for createdAt and updatedAt which is being extended by my Post entity. The Timestampable entity file is using the stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle.

**Timestampable entity**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Timestampable abstract class to define created and updated behavior
 *
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Timestampable
{
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $updatedAt;

/**
 * Set createdAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $createdAt
 * @return Timestampable
 */
public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get createdAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * Set updatedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
 * @return Timestampable
 */
public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
{
    $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updatedAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getUpdatedAt()
{
    return $this->updatedAt;
}
```

}

**Post fixture:**

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $post1 = new Post();
    $post1->setCategory($this->getReference('category-1'));
    $post1->addReply($this->getReference('reply-1'));
    $post1->addReply($this->getReference('reply-2'));
    $post1->addReply($this->getReference('reply-3'));
    $post1->setTitle('Lorem Ipsum 1');
    $post1->setAuthor('Foo1');
    $post1->setBody('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a problem with timezones vs. `Timestampable`. Your fixture data is stored in the `UTC` timezone.

See this related post (read the comments about timezones): 
[Symfony2 datetime best way to store timestamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504997/symfony2-datetime-best-way-to-store-timestamps)

This post above has a link to an interesting blog entry that can help you find a solution that best suits your scenario: 
https://matt.drollette.com/2012/07/user-specific-timezones-with-symfony2-and-twig-extensions/

**Edit:**

You may use `LifecycleCallback` to set created Value with explicit timezone.

```
/** 
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
**/

/* 
 ... 
*/

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function setCreatedValue()
{
    $now = new \DateTime('now' , new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin') );
    $this->setCreated( $now );
}
```

Comment: What is the best/ideal way to handle createdAt and updatedAt?

Comment: The linked article explains several options. If you are fine with storing the datetime in UTC, then make sure to display the underlying field with the user's timezone. If you wish to store the datetime in your timezone, then use `LifecycleCallbacks` in your entity. See update in my comment.