# How to pass a timestamp to MongoDB via the Doctrine ODM?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a RESTful API that has to receive data (user id, event id and a timestamp) and I want to save this data to MongoDB using the Doctrine ODM.

**The problem is, the timestamp is never saved in the database.**

How to do it? Also, what is the best way of performing such operations (saving data to mongoDB via the ODM?)?

This is the controller code responsible for the action:

```
    $data = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();

    $userID = $data->get('userID');
    $event = $data->get('event');
    $timestamp = $data->get('timestamp');

    $loginEvent = new LoginEvent();
    $loginEvent
        ->setEvent($event)
        ->setTimestamp($timestamp)
        ->setUserID($userID);

    $this->persist($loginEvent);

    $response = 'Saved new event for user ' . $userID;
    $view = $this->view($response,200);
    return $this->handleView($view);
```

This is the ODM Document:

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class LoginEvent{

/**
 * @MongoDB\id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\int
 */
protected $userID;

/**
 * @MongoDB\int
 */
protected $event;

/**
 * @MongoDB\timestamp
 */
protected $timestamp;

getters and setters...
```

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504997/) be of any help?

Comment: `new MongoTimestamp()`